# System.Management.ConnectionOptions always requires a password in text?

Tags: .net, asp.net, wmi, system.management

I'm using WMI in .NET to connect to remote machines in a web app.  When I initialize the connection, the Management ConnectionOptions always require a username and password in text.  I was wondering if there was a way for it to use the context of the current Windows user, eg via page.user.identity.  If I leave the connectionoptions blank then it doesn't appear to default to anything - remains null.  The reason is because I don't want the user to have to enter a logon/password - that's the whole point of Windows integrated security, right?

Any info is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549781(v=VS.100).aspx) description of the constructor for ConnectionOptions. It says that when username and password are null then the credentials of the currently logged-on user are used.

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions(...);

// Make a connection to a remote computer.
// Replace the "FullComputerName" section of the
// string "\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\cimv2" with
// the full computer name or IP address of the
// remote computer.
ManagementScope scope = 
            new ManagementScope(
            "\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\cimv2", options);
scope.Connect();
```